# Xcode assistant editor locked

Tags: xcode, editor, locked, assistant

Hi I was coding and I deleted my view controller. I added a new one but when I started coding in  the next day, I wasn't able to open the assistant editor and when I opened my other projects they were also having the same error. Also the new ones that I made, also had the same error. therefore I wasn't able to establish a connection between view controller and story board,
and there was a lock icon on the side of the assistant editor that I tried to open
when I tried to unlock the lock icon it showed

The file is a remote resource. Try making a local copy.

[this is the screenshot of how it looked like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN6YX.png)
please help

Comment: please provide more details on you problem. More screenshots and more examples.  As much more information you'll give, as faster you'll have answer on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for trouble, I found that there was problem in my derived data I simply deleted it,
the bar that shows you, your build fails and successes at the top center was showing indexing and when I clicked on run button it showed build failed the error was in my derived data.
If somebody is having the same trouble try to delete the current derived data.
maybe this error was produced because you deleted your view controller and made a new one [here see what it was showing me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ofmO.png)
**the error was no such directory** and showed me the address of the derived data I had reported to Xcode